# Problem with image when add block to page in admin

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with product block. I want to add block in admin to show list of product to home page, but image's path has problem, the "/" symbol was replaced with %5C

Present path:

```
/pub/media/catalog/product%5Ccache%5C64d10833f60a300a76b4e8c2b9c15b46%5C//b/o/botanical_interests_bean_seeds_1.png
```

I want to fix:

```
/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/64d10833f60a300a76b4e8c2b9c15b46///b/o/botanical_interests_bean_seeds_1.png
```

Just replace %5C by /, image will be shown. I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Did you manage to fix this?